# Windows Service, why are there no retries after failure after boot?

Tags: boot, reboot, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-services

I have a Windows Service, for which **I set up recovery options when the service fails** (via the Services App, in the Recovery Tab of the Service Properties).

The options currently are set so that **there is a first and second try to restart after 15 Minutes**, then reset the fail counter after a day. The startup type is automatic with delay.

While this usually works, I does not seem to make any retries after a failed start after a reboot. The following is an excerpt from the Windows Event Log:

```
11.06.2020 02:18:28 The process C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe (S701028A) has initiated the restart of computer S701028A on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Recovery (Planned) Reason Code: 0x80020002  Shutdown Type: restart  Comment:  
11.06.2020 02:20:11 The XYZ Service service entered the stopped state.
11.06.2020 02:20:16 The operating system is shutting down at system time ‎2020‎-‎06‎-‎11T00:20:16.361111600Z.
....
11.06.2020 02:20:19 The operating system started at system time ‎2020‎-‎06‎-‎11T00:20:19.490015600Z.
11.06.2020 02:24:10 The XYZ service failed to start due to the following error: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
11.06.2020 02:24:10 A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the XYZ service to connect.
```

It seems that the recovery options do only apply for process exits, not for system boots. **How can I define retries after system boot?**

*Notes:
OS Name Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
Version 6.3.9600 Build 9600*

Comment: If it's just for this computer, I would imagine setting the servicepipetimeout to 90 seconds might be the easiest thing to do if you just want to make it more reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A service's failure actions are only invoked at a defined point in a service's life cycle. From the [documentation on service failure actions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_failure_actionsa):

> A service is considered failed when it terminates without reporting a
> status of SERVICE_STOPPED to the service controller.

Implicit in that statement is that a service must have been in the SERVICE_RUNNING state prior to its unexpected exit. That is, failure actions are not invoked for a service that doesn't make it to SERVICE_RUNNING.

In your specific example, the XYZ service failed to start (i.e. it never transitioned to SERVICE_RUNNING) so no failure actions are called.